# what does AngularJS has to offer to an ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I heard a lot about how AngularJS is so much better than jQuery for communicating with server.
But all i found was replacing C# controllers and cshtml views with purely client-side javascript files. And i have no interest in that.
is anything that I'm missing?
I am currently using jQuery Ajax for communication between client and server through JSON. I was looking forward for a better solution for this purpose.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once a controller returns a view, what is sent to the browser is pure HTML.  Razor is rendered server side as HTML.  Or your action can return pure JSON.

Therefore, whether you want to use jquery, angularjs, or any other JS/HTML based library, there is really no restriction there imposed by MVC.  **From the perspective of client side code, controller actions are just URLs that return return HTML or JSON.**

Additionally, MVC controller actions which return JSON, or WebAPI controllers, are perfect RESTful endpoints for your AngularJS to interact with.  If you need HTML fragments for refreshing dynamic areas of a page, then a controller action returning a partial view will come down to the client as an HTML fragment.  So your interactive requests through Angular can still leverage your backend architecture of Controller/Business/Data layers.

### What Angular Offers MVC

AngularJS offers an MVC application the same thing it offers any web applicaion.  It is a great way to abstract the presentation of UI elements from the interactivity of those elements with the backend.  The problem with common approaches with jquery is you react to interaction with specific HTML elements via selectors such as `$('.someClass').on(...` and then in the handler collect information from the element about what was clicked and submit that in an ajax request, and then take the response and update specific elements `$('.areaToUpdate`).html(response)`.

So you have three concerns not properly separated:

- What element responds to interaction(button click, drop down change, item drag/drop)
- The interaction with the server to compile a request, submit it, and parse response.
- Updating the UI based on the server's response

Often times because of the way we try to make this code less fragile, you are restricted to a logical hierarchy of objects that also matches your UI's HTML element hierarchy.  Long story short, the lack of proper separation of concerns means changing any one will impact a chunk of code that has multiple purposes, and thus changes are more challenging because you have certain restrictions imposed due to lack of decoupling.

AngularJS provides a client side separation of these concerns by using a client side model as the intermediary between these concerns.  UI interactions update the model, other code responds to changes to the model and makes server requests which update the model in response, and yet other code can respond to those changes and update the UI in response to the model changing.  You are free to modify the UI's structure, and have a much more smaller set of code to update to get the UI changes wired up.

The fact that AngularJS is modeled from an MVC pattern makes it seem as though it would be mutually exclusive with ASP.NET MVC.  However, they serve two different purposes.  ASP.NET MVC provides separation of concerns for the server side querying of data, population of server side model, and rendering of server side HTML.  It also provides a great way to support the rendering of JSON or HTML fragments(partial views) that might be leveraged by a client side interactive framework.  AngularJS provides a model appropriate for writing clean client side code for highly interactive pages.

Personally, I think they are very complimentary.

Trying to do highly interactive pages with jquery+ASP.NET MVC is doable and can be efficient, but AngularJS adds a lot to the maintainability of the client side code.  ASP.NET MVC provides a good framework for your server side logic.  Additionally, if you have simple pages that fit a more traditionally PRG pattern or simply rendering HTML content, then ASP.NET MVC gives you an efficient way to quickly implement these pages without the unnecessary boilerplate code you'd need with Angular.  In other words, you can choose to use AngularJS only on the pages that will really benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

You can mix MVC and angularjs with out completely removing MVC controllers.E.g if you have 5 modules on your app create that parent routes on MVC routing.(E.g Students,Teachers,Attendance etc..) 
initially render your first view say student view renders through asp.net MVC then include all your  JS files(including states related to that module) on that view(e.g students.cshtml)
.JS files related to this module may be
studentModule.js,studentController.js , studentService.js etc.
Do all your CRUD operations on angular JS. 
Here your studentService will interact with MVC controller for all your db operations.
Benefit you are getting with this is

- you are interacting with  your  server asynchronously and you can use
  all angularjs features like(Directives,resources etc)
- You can authorize all your MVC controller actions with asp.net
  identity.
- -Also to render any html template on state you can call your MVC controller action from templateUrl.return csHtml from MVC controller 
  action.

There are lot of applications on live using both asp.net mvc and angular js. here are few things i know.you can check some tutorials for better understanding.
.

Answer (score 0):

Angular and ASP.net are both MVC frameworks. They are in a sense at odds with each other - I work on an Angular / ASP.net project where we serve and initial ASP.net view and then let Angular SPA routing take over, but its kind of a hack and I sometimes which we separated the two and had a plain WebApi implementation with Angular front end.

Using AngularJS just for its Http library is like using a sledge hammer when a hammer will do. You are wasting bandwidth in downloading large amounts of unused JS.

I would look to a pure JS library to handle your Http communication if you are unhappy with JQuerys implementation.

[Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) is an amazing example of one of these libraries and uses Javascript promises just like Angular - which make the whole process really neat and easy.

Good luck!